# Tensorflow table of tables input

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am currently working on a project where I need to input something that can best be described as a table of tables as input in TensorFlow, and I am wondering how to do this right.

**The problem is as follows:** 
I have a database of users who have a certain (such as "Age", "Name" and "Adress"), in addition to multiple types of events of each user (such as "Transactions", "Inventory" and "Actions"). The challenge is that each of these event types can be of different size, and logically is formed as a table. The flagging is connected to the user and not specific actions of the user, and the aim is to find other users of similar type.

**My idea:**
I am thinking of making a dict (1D) that contains fields for each the fields, that have a table (e.g. Transactions:[TABLE]) for the multi dimensional data and a single field (e.g. Name:"Leroy") for the others.

**Questions:**

1. How would the best implementation for this be? Considering
   readability, performance and results.
2. How would one best feed this to TF?
3. How would one best store this? (One file for each user or something else)

**More relevant information:**

- Data is wrangled with SQL + Python 3.6
- Number of flagged users approx 10 000
- Number of total users approx 1 million
- Total number of events per user between 100 and 10 000 +